# I need to calculate a golf score using a PHP function, but I am unable to come up with the proper equation

Tags: php, math

I am writing a function to figure out a players score for a golf game (Not a standard round of golf, but a custom game).

This figures in the actual score, the hole's handicap and the player's handicap.

For example: If the player shoots a 6, and that player's handicap is 6 and the holes handicap is a 4 the player would get a score of 5 on the hole. Here is why:

If the player's handicap is less than or equal to the hole's handicap they receive -1 point from their actual score. On an 18 hole golf course, holes have a handicap ranging from 1 to 18. So if a player has a handicap of 18 they will receive -1 point from the score of each hole. So as long as the player's handicap is 18 or less, this is easy for me to figure out. The problem I am having is how to calculate this if a player's handicap is over 18. A player could have a handicap anywhere from 1 to 99.

So if a player's handicap was 21 they would receive -1 point on all 18 holes. Then on the holes who's handicaps are 1, 2, & 3 they would receive an additional -1 point on those holes as well. So if the player's handicap was 36, they would have -2 points of their score for all holes.

This is the function I have so far:

```
function handicapCalc($hole,$player,$score){
    if($player <= 18){
        if($hole <= $player){
            $finalScore=$score-1;
        }else{
            $finalScore=$score;
        }
    }else{
        //FIGURE SCORE IF HANDICAP IS LARGER THEN 18
    }
    return $finalScore;
}
```

$hole is the variable of the hole's handicap, $player is the player's handicap & $score is the player's score.

I need to figure out a calculation to allow for a handicap over 18.

Thank you for any help you may be able to offer.

---

**EDIT [SOLVED]**

```
function handicapCalc($holeHandicap,$playerHandicap,$holes,$score){
    $perHoleHandicap=floor($playerHandicap/$holes);
    $leftOvers=$playerHandicap % $holes;

    if($perHoleHandicap >= 1){
        $firstScore=$score-$perHoleHandicap;
        if($leftOvers >= $holeHandicap){
            $finalScore=$firstScore-1;
        }else{
            $finalScore=$firstScore;
        }
    }else{
        if($perHoleHandicap >= $holeHandicap){
            $finalScore=$score-1;
        }else{
            $finalScore=$score;
        }
    }
    return $finalScore;
}
```

Comment: `(handicap % 18)+1` and `floor(handicap/18)` might be a starting point.

Comment: This is also something where writing some automated tests (even without a framework) will ease your mind while developing this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the rules properly, you just need some modulo math:

```
per-hole-handicap: floor($player_handicap / $number_of_holes)
left_over_points = $player_handicap modulo $number_of_holes
```

e.g.

handicap of 15, playing 18 holes:

```
per-hole-handicap: floor(15/18) -> 0
left_over_points = 15 mod 18 -> 15

so you've got 15 points to distribute, giving a -1 for the first 15 holes
```

handicap of 37, playing 18 holes:

```
per-hole-handicap: floor(37 / 18) -> floor(2.055) -> -2 points for all holes
left_over_points = 37 mod 18 -> 1 -> 1 extra point, so -1 for the first hole
```

Comment: Using your information, I was able to come up with a function that works. Also thanks to @Anther, I used his suggestion and wrote a script to run lots of tests to make sure it worked. You can see my modified function above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this edited variant

```
function handicapCalc($hole, $player, $score){
    $finalScore = $score - floor($player / 18) - 
        ((($player % 18) > 0 && ($player % 18) <= $hole) ? 1 : 0);
    return $finalScore;
}
```

Comment: This almost works, except it removes points too early. For example:
    echo handicapCalc(2,36,10);
returns 7, however, it should return 8. If 36 was increased to 38, then it should return 7.

Comment: I think a better way to explain the calculations is this:
write out the numbers 1-18, circle the hole's handicap. Starting at 1 count up to 18 (looping back to 1) until you get the the player's handicap. Every time you land on the hole's handicap, you get a -1. So land on it once = -1. land on it twice = -2. land on it three times and get a -3.

Comment: You are so close. You are still off by 1.

Again, this example: handicapCalc(2,36,10) returns 8 which is correcet,

handicapCalc(2,38,10) returns 7 which is correct

However handicapCalc(2,37,10) returns 7 which is wrong. It should still return 8. At 37, it has only landed on "2" twice.